# How to register path in autoload using a single instance.

Tags: php, oop, autoload

Sorry about the vague title, but I am trying to find some better alternatives to having to call an `Autoloader` class, and the `register` method multiple times, to map class paths as seen below.

```
$ClassLoader = new Autoloader\Loader(__DIR__.'/path/to/someclass');
$ClassLoader->register();

$ClassLoader = new Autoloader\Loader(_DIR__.'/path/to/anotherclass');
$ClassLoader->register();

$ClassLoader = new Autoloader\Loader(__DIR__.'/path/to/anotherclass');
$ClassLoader->register();

$ClassLoader = new Autoloader\Loader(__DIR__.'/path/to/anotherclass');
$ClassLoader->register();

$ClassLoader = new Autoloader\Loader(__DIR__.'/path/to/anotherclass');
$ClassLoader->register();
```

This goes on and on for about 50 lines, and I would like to know how I can handle the autoloading classes with simple few lines solution. I can obviously inject an array, to the constructor:

```
 $ClassLoader = new Autoloader\Loader( ['paths'=>[
                     '/path/to/class/', 
                     '/path/to/anotherclass',
                     '/path/to/anotherclass'
 ]);
 $ClassLoader->register();
```

But, I am not sure if this method is recommended at-least from OOP good practice point of view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you are looking for.
For each directory that contains your classes run `::add`.

```
namespace ClassLoader;

class Loader
{
    protected $directories = array();


    public function __construct()
    {
        spl_autoload_register([$this, 'load']);
    }

    public function add($dir)
    {
        $this->directories[] = rtrim($dir, '/\\');
    }

    private function load($class)
    {
        $classPath = sprintf('%s.php', str_replace('\\', '/', $class));

        foreach($this->directories as $dir) {
            $includePath = sprintf('%s/%s', $dir, $classPath);

            if(file_exists($includePath)) {
                require_once $includePath;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

$loader = new Loader();

$loader->add(__DIR__.'/src');
$loader->add(__DIR__.'/vendor');

use Symfony\Component\Finder\Finder;

$finder = new Finder(); 
// Included /var/www/test/vendor/Symfony/Component/Finder/Finder.php
// I put the Symfony components in that directory manually for this example.

print_r($finder);
```

It is effectively the same as with composer though, just less adaptive or performant.

Comment: @CONtext You may want to update this to cache the references to the classes that were loaded, as this version currently has a lot of IO calls.

Answer (score 1):

For this you can use Composer: https://getcomposer.org/download/

You will get a file called `composer.phar`.
Place this in your project directory, then go to that directory on your command line.

Run `php composer.phar init`.

This will ask you a few questions which you can ignore, in the end you get a new file called `composer.json`

It should look something like this:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "": "src/" }
    },
    "require": {}
}
```

Add the `autoload` field, and replace `src/` with the directory containing your classes.
Make sure that directory exists.

Then run `php composer.phar install`.

This will create a directory called `vendor`.  Inside this directory is a file called `autoload.php`.

Include this file in the bootstrap of your project, and all classes within your source directory will automatically be loaded in.

Comment: Thanks, this answer deserves more than +1, but unfortunately, I know all about composers autoload, and psr-autoloading and the rest... but since I was only trying to create a costume autloader, your answer does not quite answer my question. If you can edit, and give feedback about a solution, that would be greate

Comment: I'm not sure what else to suggest.  The way we used to do it with `spl` during the bad old days of PEAR was replacing the underscores with forward slashes to emulate what we have now.  If you are worried about breaking good practice, don't,  autoloading is a prerequisite to good practice, not necessarily good practice in itself.

Comment: Maybe [this will shed](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/60141/simple-autoloader-but-trying-to-make-it-psr-compliat) some light into the autoloader I am currently using. As you can see, what I hate is simply having to write 10 lines, to instaciate the autoloader, to map 10 different classes. So, all I need is just some alternative to take care of that

Comment: Are you running that for each individual class?  because the example in that question autoloads an entire directory of classes, recursively.

Comment: Yes, I am running (writing) that code, for each individual class. There is nothing recursive about it, it just checks if file for the class exists, based on what is being called.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into [spl_autoload_register](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) function?

**usage**

```
// pre php 5.3
function my_autoloader($class) {
    include 'classes/' . $class . '.class.php';
}
spl_autoload_register('my_autoloader');

// Or, using an anonymous function as of PHP 5.3.0
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
    include 'classes/' . $class . '.class.php';
});
```

then place all your classes in "classes" folder and when you initialise them with the `new` keyword, they will be auto-included. Works with static classes also.

for example:

```
$myClassOb1 = new MyClass();
// will include this file: classes/MyClass.class.php
```

or

```
$email = Utils::formatEmail($emailInput);
// will include this file: classes/Utils.class.php
```

Comment: I am looking for an OOP alternative. My `Autoloader` class uses `spl_autoload_register` inside, so this answer only suggests procedural solution not OO.