# Symfony2: Use github project (with namespace) as vendor bundle

Tags: php, symfony

I would like to use this php class in a symfony2 project:
https://github.com/Moinax/TvDb

Exactly like FosUserBundle:
https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md

I managed to install the package through composer in my vendor directory with:

```
composer moinax/tvdb
```

What do I need to do now?
Please note that my folder structure (created automatically by composer) now is:

```
vendor/moinax/tvdb/(content of the github project)
```

**Note:**
in simple php (no Symfony2) this is the code of the most basic usage example:

```
// examples/index.php (look at the github project for folder structure)    
include __DIR__ . '/settings.php';
include __DIR__ . '/../src/Moinax/TvDb/Http/HttpClient.php';
include __DIR__ . '/../src/Moinax/TvDb/Http/CurlClient.php';
include __DIR__ . '/../src/Moinax/TvDb/CurlException.php';
include __DIR__ . '/../src/Moinax/TvDb/Client.php';
include __DIR__ . '/../src/Moinax/TvDb/Serie.php';
include __DIR__ . '/../src/Moinax/TvDb/Banner.php';
include __DIR__ . '/../src/Moinax/TvDb/Episode.php'; 

use Moinax\TvDb\Client;
$apiKey = 'YOURAPIKEY';

$tvdb = new Client("http://thetvdb.com", $apiKey);
$tvdb->getSerie(75710);
```

I want to do the same thing inside a controller of the AcmeDemoBundle... in other words: from the DefaultController inside the AcmeDemoBundle, I want to create a `$tvdb = new Client("http://thetvdb.com", $apiKey);` object based on the class defined in the moinax/tvdb script saved as a vendor.

Comment: Have you tried it?  Based on what you posted, composer should have taken care of autoloading for you.  You can forget about all the include stuff in the examples.  It should just work.

Comment: I managed to get it working but there are still some things that may be refined... Question: if I save this class in the vendor folder (as default) what path do I need to use in the "use" statement? How can I include an asset that is located in the vendor folder?

Comment: The exact same namespace you showed in your question.  vendor/autoload.php takes care of mapping the namespace to specific file folders.  Part of the magic of composer.

Comment: @Cerad You are right... now everything works. Please post your explanation as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1):

I think my answer to this question will help you:
[How to register path in autoload using a single instance.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25790464/how-to-register-path-in-autoload-using-a-single-instance/25792154#25792154)

Basically you want to include the `vendor/autoload.php` file, but you may also want to configure composer to autoload your project source directory as well as the vendors.